# Not able to by-pass password prompts in File opening

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a file in VBA. I am using the following code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myArray = ActiveSheet.Range("M1:M5")

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.InitialFileName = "Desktop"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen = -1 Then

For j = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(j), ReadOnly:=True,Password:=myArray(i, 1))
        Debug.Print myArray(i, 1)
       If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next i
   'Processing the File 
Next j

End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Array Contains my Password. When I open it manually, it asks for password to access and when I enter the password, it again prompts for a password which is for write access. I also get an option to read only the second time and I have already put that in my code. Also I have given alll the possible passwords in my array M1:M5. so I don't know whats the problem coming . can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Edit : It throws ab Run-time error '1004' 
The password you supplied is not correct. Verify that the Caps lock key is off and be sure to use the correct capitalization. I also want to make it clear that there are two different passwords on the file.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think that the password that VBA is looking for is the Workbook protection password (set up in the Excel file), not the Windows level password, which is what you seem to have set.

Comment: I have setup all the passwords in excel sheet only from where I run the code. Also all the files open when I use path directly and open

Answer (score 0):

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(j), ReadOnly:=True,Password:=myArray(i, 1))
```

is only supplying one password `Password:=myArray(i, 1)`. Since two passwords are required, you'll need to supply the other one, as well with `WriteResPassword:=<something>`.

From the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx):

> **WriteResPassword** A string that contains the password required to write to a write-reserved workbook. If this argument is omitted **and the workbook requires a password**, *the user will be prompted for the password*.

<sup>**both** *emphasis* added</sup>

I believe the fact that you're specifying `ReadOnly:=True` will keep it read only, but someone has to specify the `Write` password, your code or your user.

It looks to me like your loop code

```
For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(j), ReadOnly:=True,Password:=myArray(i, 1))
    Debug.Print myArray(i, 1)
   If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then Exit For
Next i
```

is attempting to open each file selected with each password. I would assume you've not hit any errors yet because your first password provided matches the first file selected. As soon as it doesn't, your loop will exit, and you'll never get to trying another password on that first file.

Also, as a side note, I would recommend moving the `Dim wb2 As Workbook` out of the loops - put it at the top of the code.

Comment: In the mean time I have already tried whatever you suggested. What i did was introducing K as another variable and introducing one more loop inside i and putting WriteResPassword =myArray(k,1). Is that wrong because I again get the same error? . I think putting two loops should check for all the possible passwords right? it will be three loops in total.

Comment: Adding another loop and trying to open the workbook again by passing a different password won't help. You need to pass both passwords when you open the file: `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(j), ReadOnly:=True, Password:=myArray(i, 1)), WriteResPassword:=<something>`. `<something>` may be `myArray(i,2)` (I'm guessing since you have a 2-dimentional array, but haven't shown what you're populating in it), or it may be stored somewhere else.